# contenteditable= false not working

Tags: html, contenteditable

I have a **div that is editable for unknown reason** (I don't want it to be editable) and even if i try `contenteditable="false"` it doesn't solve the problem.

I thought maybe it has to do with some plugins conflict, but disabling any wordpress plugins wouldn't help. i use CKeditor so i thought it might cause the problem, but disabling it also doesn't solve the problem.

**Any Ideas?**

Answer (score 4):

Stupid me, i had a `-webkit-user-modify: read-write;` on this class which made it editable. now i need to find out why did i add this :)